# CSS Class applies, but style doesn't change

Tags: html, css

My html elements have the CSS classes, I can clearly see them when I inspect elements in the browser (F12) but there are no style changes.

This is my reference to my css page:

```
<link href="MyCSSPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And this is my actual CSS page:

```
.rightMargin {
margin-right: 30px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

And my html element looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="300px" CssClass="rightMargin" />
```

The strange thing is, when I had the CSS right on my aspx page with the style tags around it, it all worked. Any ideas?

Here's how the code appears in the DOM explorer:

```
<input name="txtUsername" type="text" id="txtUsername" class="rightMargin" style="height:50px;width:300px;">
```

```css
.rightMargin {
margin-right: 30px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input name="txtUsername" type="text" id="txtUsername" class="rightMargin" style="height:50px;width:300px;" />
```

Comment: try adding `display:inline-block;`

Comment: thats ASP code, instead please add the html as it appears on the browser

Comment: Added the html.

Comment: Add also the HTML in which your `input` is wrapped.

Comment: Is your CSS path correct? Since the css styles were working when called inline, not linking properly could be a reason. Do check that.

Comment: I added it as a snippet to your question using your code and the class works fine. Are you sure you are just not overlooking the result because your margin is on the right and the element automatically is on the left?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation. In the inspector I saw the class being added by an event listener, but the style attached to it was not visible on the page.

I had the following code:

```
div {
style: working;}}

div.highlight {
style: not-working;}
```

As you can see, I had an unwanted `}` at the end of the first block, left by accident, so the second block was ignored by the browser.

*As I was searching through SO, I saw many questions related to similar problems by various reasons. I hope my answer helps someone in the future.*